# Can't Get Info From Localstorage - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm learning how to use localstorage in JavaScript, so I made an application to get some practice. When I ran the code it gave me this error:

[image: ERROR]

I put the html and css on a codepen, here is the link:
[Link To Code](https://codepen.io/thejseffect/pen/wgrajV?editors=1111)

JavaScript Code

```
// READY
$(document).ready(() => {
    // when user clicks on submit
    $(".submit").on("click", addItem);

    // show bookmarks
    showBookmarks();
})

// ADD ITEM
let addItem = (e) => {
    // get values from inputs
    let name = $(".name").val();
    let link = $(".url").val();

    // stores bookmarks
    let bookmark = {
        name: name,
        url: link
    };

    // bookmark varification
    // if theres nothing in bookmarks
    if(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") == null) {
        // init array
        let bookmarks = [];
        // add to array
        bookmarks.push(bookmark);
        // set to local storage
        localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    } else { // if theres something in bookmarks
        // get from local storage
        let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));
        // add bookmark to array
        bookmarks.push(bookmark);
        // reset back to local storage
        localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    }

    // prevent form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
}

// SHOW BOOKMARKS
let showBookmarks = () => {
    // get from local storage
    let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));

    // loop through local storage data
    for(let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
        let name = bookmarks.name[i];
        let url = bookmarks.url[i];

        // append bookmarks
        $(".show").append(`
            <div class="bookmarks-container">
                <div class="bookmark">
                    <a href="${url}" target="_blank">${name}</a>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        `);
    }
}

// DELETE ITEM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to change:

```
for(let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
        let name = bookmarks.name[i];
        let url = bookmarks.url[i];
```

to:

```
for(let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
        let name = bookmarks[i].name;
        let url = bookmarks[i].url;
```

This is because I was cycling through `name` and `url` but, I'm tell the browser at the start of my for loop to cycle through `bookmarks`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `showBookmarks` method on load which then tries to parse the `localStorage` "bookmarks" item. That value is undefined when it tries to loop through it and undefined has no length.

```
if(!bookmarks){
        return;
    }
```

[Here is the example working](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNEGVP?editors=1111)

Comment: the example link isn't working, also I'm not sure where I should place the `showBookmarks()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let bookmarks = localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") !== null ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks")) : [];
```